# Unsubscribe numbers not getting updated in the EXM Dashboard

Tags: exm

On `Sitecore 9.0.1`, we are sending emails to users through `Sitecore EXM` using custom functionality. While everything is running smooth, we found that whenever a user unsubscribes from the email campaign, the number does not reflect in the `EXM dashboard` for the email campaign.

As can be seen below from the screenshot, all the other details are getting updated properly while the unsubscribe data is always 0.

[image]

Comment: are you using Sitecore unsubscribe functionality or custom SMTP unsubscribe? will you be able to paste the URL that is formed once you hover (or click) on unsubscribe CTA in the email?

Comment: Hi Raman, we are using custom unsubscribe where the user is redirected to an unsubscribe page. Everything is handled via code in the backend and it works fine like the user is removed from the mailing list and I can see an unsubscribe event also in the user profile but just that the number is not getting updated in the dashboard. I won't be able to share the URL unfortunately.